# EPS8266 ESP-01: LED manipulation seems to interfere with serial communication

Tags: serial, esp8266, led, arduino-nano, wifi

I'm playing around with this [udp-example](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/esp8266wifi/udp-examples.rst). Both this and the blink-example work perfectly. Now I would like to use the LED to indicate what the ESP is currently doing, as well as reading some data over Serial. My code looks like this:

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setTimeout(500);
  while(Serial.available()==0){
  }
  String password = Serial.readStringUntil('.');
  Serial.println(password);
  WiFi.begin(ssid.c_str(), password.c_str());
  //pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    //digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); 
    delay(250);
    //digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); 
    delay (250);
  }
  Serial.println("connected");
  Udp.begin(localUdpPort);
}
```

It works fine, but if I uncomment the led-lines the serial communication doesn't seem to work anymore. All the stuff that is printed on the Serial Monitor is now messed up (missing characters, ...). Is there a problem with my code or what else could be possible going wrong here?

EDIT: I recently tried the same code again, but used an additional power supply (3.3V, 500mA) for the chip. However, this didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Turn the baud rate down to 9600 and see if that helps.  Also not sure about the `setTimeout` call.

Comment: Setting the baud rate to 9600 has no effect when the led stuff is commented out, but if it's not commented I cant see anything on SerialMonitor at all ( setTimeout is also commented out)

Comment: Do you have a drivers to the LEDs or are they directly attached to the ESP-01? And have you a extra capacitor as power stabilizer over Vcc and GND?

Comment: It is the built in led on the esp I am using. I just connected VCC to VCC of my usb/ftdi- chip (which is plugged in on my notebook).

Comment: I'm using this chip from AzDelivery  FTDI Adapter FT232RL

Comment: i would suggest you add something to the body of that while loop, just to allow the background activities to continue, even if it's just a short `delay` or a `yield`

Comment: Do you mean the first one? Why should this change something?

Comment: Do you get the same results with another module? Did you enter anything through the serial monitor? Can you place a `while (1);` after the `Serial.println(password)` to see if that at least is printed? Maybe also place a `yield()`  in the `while (Serial.available() == 0) { }` loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would bet that the built-in LED pin is also the TX pin for the serial interface.

Check here, **LED Pin** section: http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=esp8266_gpio_pin_allocations

> LED Pin
>
> GPIO1, which is also TX, is wired to the blue LED on many devices.
>   Note that the LED is active low (connected to Vcc and sinks through
>   the chip to ground) so setting a logical value of 0 will light it up.
>   Since GPIO1 is also the TX pin, you won't be able to blink the LED and
>   perform Serial communications at thew same time unless you switch
>   TX/RX pins.

This would be confirmed if the LED blinks when serial communication is active.

If this is the case you would have to add your own LED on a different pin, or switch the RX/TX pins.

Comment: I agree, ref. https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/3165